# is there is any direct method in JDK to get CPU usage on machine either its mac, windows or linux?

Tags: java, cpu-usage

I have a application in which I have to show cpu & ram usage, I tried so many thing, however haven't got any accurate solution. So, finally end-up with **programmatically querying for CPU usage is impossible using pure Java. There is simply no API for this** on a blog post

Blog link: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077361/learn-java/profiling-cpu-usage-from-within-a-java-application.html

.

What i have tried (i am using java 1.8):

```
OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
System.out.println("========="+  osBean.getSystemLoadAverage());

MemoryMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
System.out.println("######"+  bean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage());

ThreadMXBean mxbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
System.out.println("========="+ mxbean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime());
```

Comment: Please don't spam-tag your questions. This has nothing to do with Oracle, for example.

Comment: Downvoters, please mention reason for your downvote too.

Comment: Dev - I agree completely with your request for downvoters to explain their reasons. (I would even advocate for SO to make it a requirement - even if it's with anonymous comments, which may be a pain to code for the site). For the record, I don't downvote for spam-tags, I just comment on that. You have **two** downvoters who didn't explain what they found wrong with your question. Note though that on SO the majority of downvoters do **not** explain their votes.

Answer (score 2):

Well I had to do something like that sometimes ago and I didn't find an easy and native way to do it.

After some research anyway I found a quite cool library that can be used for this kind of task and supports a good variety of OSs. You should take a look [here](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) at OSHI, a free JNA-based (native) Operating System and Hardware Information library for Java.